# Possible to specify what fields a belongs_to or has_many relationship object(s) return(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A Contact has a User assigned to them:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :user
    ...
end
```

The user model has a field I want to exclude any time a user object or objects are returned from db. One of the ways to make it work is to add a default scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :contacts
    ...

    default_scope select((column_names - ['encrypted_password']).map { |column_name| "`#{table_name}`.`#{column_name}`"})
end
```

So in console if I do:

```
User.first
```

The select statement and result set do not include 'encrypted_password'.

However, if I do:

```
c = Contact.includes(:user).first

c.user
```

they do. The default scope on the User model does not get applied in this case and the 'encrypted_password' field is shown.

So my question is why? And also, is there a clean way to specify what fields should be returned on related object(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use the :select option on the belongs_to relationship.  Something like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user, :select => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Sweet! While this works in removing my encrypted_password field, it still shows fields not specified in the belongs_to :select array. Might have something to do with User including Devise modules. So any ideas why my approach of using a default_scope didn't do the job?